# Search for shape by name using wildcard

Tags: excel, vba

I have a box in which is the number 1:
[image]

As I will add automatically the new sheet I would like to have this number increasing by 1.

```vb
Sub otdr()
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Lastrow As Long
    Dim xNumber As Long, yNumber As Long
    Dim otdr As Range, desc As Range, fet As Range, boxdesc As Range
    Dim xName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wk As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set ws = Sheets("OTDR TRACE - 1")
    Set wk = Sheets("Fibre drop release sheet")
    Set fet = wk.Range("E3")
    Set otdr = ws.Range("Q46")
    Set desc = ws.Range("B52")
    Set boxdesc = ws.Range("B60")
    xNumber = Sheets("Frontsheet").Range("D32").Value
    
    Lastrow = wk.Cells(wk.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To (xNumber - 1)
         otdr = "OT " & (i + 1) & " of " & Number
         desc = fet.offset(1, 1)
         ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
         ActiveSheet.Range("B60").Value = i + 1
         ActiveSheet.Name = "OTDR TRACE - " & i + 1
      
         For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
             If shp Like "Rectangle" Then
                 shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = boxdesc
             End If
         Next shp
    Next
    
    ws.Activate
    otdr = "OT 1 of " & Number
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

I get an error:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

with debugger pointing to the following line:

```vb
If shp Like "Rectangle" Then
```

How can I copy the rectangle to the newly copied sheet with the number increased?

The `like` statement is the wildcard in VBA Excel. The name of my rectangle is initially "Rectangle 1". In the new sheet it is changed to "Rectangle 2". What is wrong with this wildcard then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare an object (a `Shape Object`) with a string...

Then, in order to make `Like` operator work, you must use the wild character in the next way:

```
If shp.Nme Like "Rectangle*" Then
```

Or use `Instr` in the next way:

```
If InStr(1, shp.Name, "rectangle", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

This last version is not case sensitive, too...